# Arrowizing the Store comonad

Tags: haskell, category-theory, arrows, comonad

I've been contributing for a past few weeks to a library that ports monads (mainly from `mtl`) to arrows.

Here's a quick example with the `StateT` monad from `mtl`:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
-- arrowization -->
newtype StateTA s a b c = StateTA { runStateTA :: a (b, s) (c, s) }
```

The "arrowizing" process wasn't really painful for most of the monads, but I can't figure out my arrow based on the Store comonad.

Every time I asked this question, people redirected me to the `Cokleisli` arrow, but will `Cokleisli Store` be equivalent to the arrow I'm looking for ?

The library being based on a `mtl`-style architecture (each arrow has a general class, like `ArrowState`, `ArrowReader`, etc...), I tried to figure out what will be the signatures of my functions in `ArrowStore`, but again, I can't.

I took a look at the `arrows` package which implements the same arrows as in the library I'm working on, but their `CoState` arrow (I heard CoState was another name for Store) defines no operations, so I guess the author also has troubles with this problem.

tl;dr:

- Is `Monad m => Kleisli m a b` equivalent to the arrowized version `m` ?
- Is it also true for comonads with the `Cokleisli` arrow ?
- If so, how can I express the `Store` comonad as an arrow ?
- If not, can we even "arrowize" comonads ?

Comment: In short: _yes, the co-Kleisli category is what you want_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: If it is equivalent, why didn't the authors of the `arrows` package just made types aliases ? (for arrow transformers I guess, but not sure)

Comment: Well, ask Ross Paterson... I don't know about the motivation for the `arrows` package specifically, but I think it's definitely interesting to _see_ how these special Kleisli arrows look in “direct form”, hence the desire to not just newtype a Kleisli. However, I think [`CoStateArrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-CoState.html) is actually not quite right – this is a curried form with one base arrow replaced by a **Hask** one. I'd think it should be `a (s->b, s) c`. Or even actually `a (a s b, c)`.

Comment: I think if you want a good discussion on this topic you will have to give a better (read: formal) definition of 'arrowizing' - from the example it isn't clear precisely what you want. It doesn't seem to be the act of replacing arrows with type parameters of kind `* -> * -> *` , nor does it seem to refer to the fact that every arrow gives rise to a monad and v.v. ([WrappedMonad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedMonad), WrappedArrow, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [leftaroundabout's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961774/arrowizing-the-store-comonad?noredirect=1#comment67203489_39961774), I found the "arrowized" version of the `Store` comonad.

My problem was that I couldn't find the "direct form" - as leftaroundabout mentions it - of my arrow. But, if what I want is `Cokleisli Store` then the answer is straightforward (not very formal notation but you get the idea):

```
newtype CokleisliT a w b c = CokleisliT { runCokleisliT :: a (w b) c }
newtype Store s a = Store (s -> a, s)

    Arrow a => CokleisliT a (Store s) b c
<=> Arrow a => a (Store s b) c
<=> Arrow a => a (s -> b, s) c
```

From here, we can deduce the signatures of the `ArrowStore` class:

```
class Arrow a => ArrowStore s a | a -> s where
    pos   :: a () s
    peek  :: a () b -> a s b
    peeks :: a () b -> a (s -> s) b
    seek  :: a (s, b) c -> a b c
    seeks :: a (s, b) c -> a (s -> s, b) c
```

As for [user's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961774/arrowizing-the-store-comonad#comment67208923_39961774), apparently arrowizing a (co)monad is wrapping it in a (co)Kleisli arrow.

Here's the library for the other arrows: https://github.com/felko/atl.